# Testing Angular 2 service with mocha

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, mocha.js

I am trying to implement unit tests for an Angular 2 app. But I can't get it it to work. 
As test runner **mocha** is used and executed like this:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register -t 10000 ./**/*.unit.ts
```

Consider the following test file where I define two test cases which basically should do the same thing, but neither one is working.

**shared.service.unit.ts**

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';
import * as Chai from 'chai';
import 'mocha';
const expect = Chai.expect;

describe('SharedService', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SharedService],
            providers: [SharedService]
        });
    });

    it('should be an object',
        inject([SharedService], (service: SharedService) => {
            expect(service).to.be.an('object');
        })
    );
});

describe('SharedService without the TestBed', () => {
    let service: SharedService;

    beforeEach(() => { 
        service = new SharedService();
    });

    it('should be an object', () => {
        expect(service).to.be.an('object');
    });
});
```

The first one `'SharedService'` uses the [Angular Testing Utility](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#atu-apis). Running it gives:

> ReferenceError: Zone is not defined

The second one `'SharedService without TestBed'`does not use any Angular code (similar to [this example from Angular 2 Testing guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#isolated-unit-tests)). Running it gives:

> TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function

After adding these lines to the test file:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Both test cases give the same error (from `zone.js\dist\zone.js`):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, just needed to `import 'core-js/es7/reflect'`:

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'mocha';
import * as Chai from 'chai';
let expect = Chai.expect;
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';

describe('SharedService', () => {
    let service: SharedService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        service = new SharedService();
    })

    it('should be an object', () => {
        expect(service).to.be.an('object');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load all that stuff - angular, ngzone, metadata, es shims, etc. - statically in the mocha's - or systemjs or whatever you use for setting this stuff up - configuration.